# Save different version of wheel files of a python package into a local directory

Tags: python, pip, python-3.7, pypi, python-wheel

I am running **pip3 wheel -r requirements.txt -w /wheel_files/** command to store the wheel files of different packages into the local filesystem.

I have package A of version v1 which internally depends on package C of version v3 and package B of version v2 which depends on package C of version v1. while running the pip3 wheel command to create the wheel files and save them to the local filesystem, it is ignoring version v1 of package C as version v3 of package C is already saved into the local folder. How can I save both the versions of v1 and v3 of package C into the file system?

I am using pip version 20.2.4

Answer (score 1):

Just download it:

```
pip download --only-binary :all: --dest /wheel_files/ --no-cache C==v1
```

The part where you say that A depends on C v3 and B depends on C v1 sounds a bit scary. If it was the case that:

```
A depends on B
A depends on C==v3 (note equality!)
B depends on C==v1 (note equality!)
```

Then you are busted, as pip will not be able to satisfy the conflicting dependiences. So you probably have

```
A depends on B
A depends on C>=v3
B depends on C>=v1
```

and that's why you only get C v3, as v3 satisfies both.

Comment: but pip 20.2.4 can handle this scenario if those packages are installed manually, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I'd be very surprised if that was the case.